# My page title turns into a h2 tag - What to do?

Tags: pages

When i create a frontpage or another page or post, the titles i choose in the editor become h2-tags when the page or post is launched.

I would very much like this to be a h1-tag instead. Can i change this setting anywhere?

Theme name is 'Rocked' and my website is http://filmhygge.dk.

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter the template files under the theme folder. In the folder `template-parts` there is `content-page.php` that renders the page (well, at least the part with the header) and `content-single.php` that has the single post's title part.

Just change the `<h2>` and `</h2>` tags to be `<h1>` and `</h1>` respectively on the `<?php the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title">', '</h2>' ); ?>` part.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Although i tried this and it didn't change anything. The title on my front page is still a h2 tag. Is it just a matter of waiting for some time for it to update properly?

Comment: I think the home page part might come from the `content.php` file. Did you change that also? Well, all the files (except content-none) under the template-parts folder have the <h2> tag in them it seems :)

Comment: Yeah I changed all of them from h2 to h1 now. Still no difference though. I am not using FTP-software tho (as i have no idea how to use it), so I'm just making the changes in the backend of my webhosting provider. Maybe it's just slow?

Comment: Sure it's possible there's some kind of caching going on, so to be sure, wait for a while. With a quick searh there's also some <h2 tags in functions.php, under "site branding" and "header text", don't know if those might have some effect on it as well.

Comment: It appears to be updated now! Thanks a lot :-). Next problem is that the fontsize of the title is now so much smaller than the other headings, haha.. Gotta try and fix that though :)

Comment: Well good, and yes the problem with the size is probably because the theme developer has styled the h2 tags to be the "correct" size. I don't quite understand why you wanted to change them in the first place, but I think its time for you to go fiddle with the style.css :)